# AppCompatDialog vs DialogFragment

Tags: android, dialog, android-appcompat, android-dialogfragment

With the latest AppCompat

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1"
```

There is both available `AppCompatDialog` and `DialogFragment` which one should I prefer are there any differences or problems that can I avoid?

**Edit:**

I tried to use either the `AppCompatDialog` or `DialogFragment` by converting an existing `Dialog` that I had, but in none the `getDialog().setTitle("Title")` seem to work.

Comment: The [DialogFragment][1] and the [AppCompatDialog][2] are completely different.[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html
  [2]: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialog.html

Answer (score -1):

### Update 17 May 2021:

Quoting from [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs):

> A dialog is a small window that prompts the user to make a decision or enter additional information. A dialog does not fill the screen and is normally used for modal events that require users to take an action before they can proceed.
>
> You should use a `DialogFragment` as a container for your dialog. The `DialogFragment` class provides all the controls you need to create your dialog and manage its appearance, instead of calling methods on the `Dialog` object.
>
> Using `DialogFragment` to manage the dialog ensures that it correctly handles lifecycle events such as when the user presses the Back button or rotates the screen. The `DialogFragment` class also allows you to reuse the dialog's UI as an embeddable component in a larger UI, just like a traditional `Fragment` (such as when you want the dialog UI to appear differently on large and small screens).

Note: `AppCompatDialog` is a `Dialog` extension.

---

### Previous answer (Nov 16 '19):

The [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html) and the [AppCompatDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialog.html) are completely different.

---

*As per [Gabriele Mariotti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2016562/gabriele-mariotti) comment.*

Comment: what is the different ?